# Video capturing crash on Samsung android 5 with FileProvider

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, android-camera-intent, android-fileprovider

Model: Samsung SM-G900F (Android 5.0)

Code to launch camera:

```
        File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null),"video.mp4");

        Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "example.com.myapplication.fileprovider", file);

        final Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            takePictureIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION| Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        } else {
            final List<ResolveInfo> resInfoList =
                    getPackageManager()
                            .queryIntentActivities(takePictureIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);

            for (final ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resInfoList) {
                final String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
                grantUriPermission(packageName, uri,
                                   Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION |
                                   Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            }
        }
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, 42);
```

Log:

```
11-03 11:40:00.073 30377-30377/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: com.sec.android.app.camera, PID: 30377
                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=2002, result=-1, data=Intent { act=inline-data dat=content://example.com.myapplication.fileprovider/external/Android/data/example.com.myapplication/files/video.mp4 (has extras) }} to activity {com.sec.android.app.camera/com.sec.android.app.camera.Camcorder}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3974)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4017)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:172)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1471)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
                                                    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
                                                       at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetLong(Native Method)
                                                       at android.database.CursorWindow.getLong(CursorWindow.java:524)
                                                       at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getLong(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:75)
                                                       at android.database.CursorWrapper.getLong(CursorWrapper.java:106)
                                                       at com.sec.android.app.camera.Camera.onActivityResult(Camera.java:6956)
                                                       at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6475)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3970)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4017) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:172) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1471) 
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

Looks like video capturing works only with file uri and doesn't work with content uri.

Do you have the same issues? Could you suggest some general solution?

Answer (score 4):

This helped me:

```
    Uri uri;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", f);
    } else {
        uri = Uri.fromFile(f);
    }
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
```

Comment: Bless you! I have no idea why Android had pictures using the old OS have to do weird stuff but not Video, but this was a life saver.

Answer (score -1):

This is working for me.

```
private void launchCamera() {

    Intent captureVideoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
    if (captureVideoIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null)
    {
        Uri videoUri = null;
        try {
            videoUri = getOutputMediaFileUri();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (videoUri != null) {
            captureVideoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, videoUri);
            startActivityForResult(captureVideoIntent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Creating file uri to store image/video
 */
private Uri getOutputMediaFileUri() {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {
        // For android N you need to use the file provider
        return FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, getResources().getString(R.string.file_provider_name), getOutputMediaFile());
    } else {
        return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile());
    }
}


/**
 * returning file to store image / video 
 */
private File getOutputMediaFile() {
    // External sdcard location
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(
            Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
            "DirectoryNameWhereYouWantToStore");

    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Oops! Failed to create directory");
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Create a media file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
    return new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".mp4");
}
```